# How convert byte array to image by PIL in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I recieve bytes of image from C# by socket as following:

```
[u'69', u'20', u'80', u'1', u'69', u'20', u'80', u'7', u'255', u'217']
```

I want to save this array as a jpg, I used PIL, but I can't do it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: ... and what did you find by searching? This has come up several times just on Stack Exchange ..

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
import Image, ImageDraw

im=Image.new(valuetype, (width,height), None)
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.point((x,y),value)
im.save(file, "JPEG")
```

If you can't figure it out, post what problem you are having.